# EPSON TM-82 printer

Tags: epson

I am using EPSON TM-82 printer (POS) in windows 7.

Sometimes the printer doesn't work when I give print option from the application. The printer starts working after I restart the system.

Any reasons for that? Is it because the printer is idle for sometime, in that case how can we avoid that (how to increase the idle time)?

Thanks.

Comment: Communicate directly with it via TCP/IP.

Comment: It can be that incomplete commands were sent to the printer and until this command is terminated it will hang. When you reset the printer you also delete the command buffer.